# Custom Project Views in Podio

Tags: php, api, podio

I was wondering if there is a way to customize views for a Project based on 
the type of employee? For instance, our Project Managers only need access to both view/modify specific fields on a project like budget, etc. The folks on the fabrication floor would need even less. Administrators would always have full access to all, etc.

Even if this had to be defined statically in a file, that'd work (we don't

In researching through the API and Podio docs, there is only a way to modify views by type of project, but not on Project fields themselves. I could think of a way to do this in CSS/JS via a Tampermonkey script, but was wondering of a less "hack-y" way where it's actually in Podio and not on each person's machine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no way to adjust fields displayed based upon user type.

One thing which might be helpful would be to use calculated fields with logic to determine 'user type' and adjust accordingly for the sensitive fields. Definitely not ideal but the podio security model doesn't support field level security model.